# gvisMotionChart: change the default variables

Tags: r, googlevis

I have a `data.frame` `df` that consists of fours sites (1 to 4). Each site has values for four parameters (A to D) from 2011 to 2014. I want to create a motion chart for site1.

```
library(dplyr)
siteID <- c(rep("site1", 16), rep("site2", 16), rep("site3", 16), rep("site4", 16))
YEAR <-   as.numeric(rep(c("2011", "2012", "2013", "2014"), 16))
parameter <- c(rep("A", 4), rep("B", 4), rep("C", 4), rep("D", 4),
               rep("A", 4), rep("B", 4), rep("C", 4), rep("D", 4),
               rep("A", 4), rep("B", 4), rep("C", 4), rep("D", 4),
               rep("A", 4), rep("B", 4), rep("C", 4), rep("D", 4))
value <- c(seq(1, 4, by=1), seq(10, 40, by=10), seq(12, 18, by=2), seq(5, 20, by=5),
           seq(3, 12, by=3), sample(13:18, 4), sample(15:22, 4), sample(10:18, 4),
           seq(7, 1, by=-2), sample(15:22, 4), sample(15:19, 4), sample(10:20, 4),
           seq(8, 5, by=-1), seq(50, 20, by=-10), seq(16, 10, by=-2), seq(20, 5, by=-5))
df <- data.frame(siteID, YEAR, parameter, value)
df$YEAR <- as.numeric(df$YEAR)

df1 <- df %>%
  dplyr::filter(siteID =="site1")
```

I created the motion chart for site 1 using the following code

```
library(googleVis)
site1 = gvisMotionChart(data=df1, 
                         idvar="parameter", 
                         timevar="YEAR",
                         chartid="site1")
plot(site1)
```

It worked fine. The result is here

[image]

However, the default `x axis` and `y axis` were `value`. I had to change `x axis` myself from value to YEAR.

I wanted to change the default values so that `x-axis` will be `YEAR`, `colorvar` will be `parameter`, and `sizevar` will be `value`. I did that using this code

```
site1_1 = gvisMotionChart(data=df1, 
                         idvar="parameter", 
                         timevar="YEAR",
                         chartid="site1",
                         xvar="YEAR", 
                         yvar="value",
                         colorvar="parameter", 
                         sizevar="value")

plot(site1_1)
```

It kept showing as loading but the plot was not created.
Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Hi, in your df, at each time point, you need both x & y values. Thus for 2011 for instance. You need both x & y values for parameter A, B, C, D. All you provide are the x values. Can you give extra information?

Comment: @user1357015
Thanks for your help. As I mentioned in my question, the plot is working fine but the default axis is value for x axis and y-axis. I had to change x axis to be Time (YEAR). Is there any way to make it by default Time.

Comment: No -- it's not working fine. In fact on the x-axis you're plotting "value" and on the y-axis you're plotting "value". If you were to plot "YEAR" as the x-value you would get the values line up vertically instead of a diagonal line.

Comment: @user1357015
Thanks. I got them vertically as shown in the graph above by changing the x-value to YEAR.

Comment: bingo! So what is it that you need it to do now?

Comment: I did that manually after I got the plot. I was trying to check if there is a way to make it by default in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the below should get you just about there. All that's left is to set the options appropriately to get rid of the commas and such.

```
df1 <- df %>%
  dplyr::filter(siteID =="site1") %>%
  mutate(Date = YEAR) %>%
  mutate(colorValue = parameter) %>%
  mutate(sizeValue = value)



library(googleVis)
site1 = gvisMotionChart(data=df1, 
                        idvar="parameter", 
                        timevar="YEAR",
                        chartid="site1",
                        xvar = "Date",
                        yvar = "value",
                        colorvar = "colorValue",
                        sizevar = "sizeValue")
plot(site1)
```

Comment: One more point, I tried to add a title options=list(title = "My gVIS Motion Chart") but it won't appear on the plot. Any suggestions would be highly appreciated.

Comment: There is no title option for a motion chart. See here: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/motionchart#setting-initial-state

Other chart types have title under configuration options -- not this type.